# Special characters (i.e. "?") displaying in front of text area

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am building a Wordpress site using the free Responsive theme by Cyberchimps, and am running into a problem where special characters entered at the end of a text field are being pushed to the front of the text field when published. I have sifted through my sites CSS and can't find where the problem is, any ideas?

example: Text will be entered as "Hey, how are you?" will be displayed on the site as "?Hey, how are you"

Comment: Sounds like problem with some text-direction setting somewhere, right-to-left instead of left-to-right …

Comment: That was the problem! The body was set to right-to-left. Thank you.

Comment: Kay, added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Text will be entered as "Hey, how are you?" will be displayed on the site as "?Hey, how are you"

Sounds like problem with some text-direction setting somewhere, right-to-left instead of left-to-right – with a language that is not rtl itself, that usually only affects the punctuation marks.